# Как отсортировать массив с пользователями по id?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

Есть json:

```js
    "users": [
        {
            "user": "us1",
            "id": 20,
 
        },
        {
            "user": "us2",
            "id": 3,
        },
        {
            "user": "us3",
            "id": 17,
        },
    ],
```

Как отсортировать пользователей по id, чтобы сначала был пользователь с меньшим id и дальше по возрастанию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const users =
  [
    {
      "user": "us1",
      "id": 20,
    },
    {
      "user": "us2",
      "id": 3,
    },
    {
      "user": "us3",
      "id": 17,
    },
  ];

const sortUsersId = array => {
  const result = array.sort((a, b) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1);

  return result;
}

console.log(sortUsersId(users));
```